# Convert 8199000000 to decimal (php)

Tags: php, decimal

The API I fetch my data with, returns me 8199000000 for the price.
Which should be 81.99 but I should also expect something like 15499000000 which should result into 154.99.

How can I parse that clean and nice?

Comment: Why not `1549.9`?

Comment: Why don't you remove 6 zero's and put a comma/dot on the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just divide by 1e8 (1 and 8 zeroes).

```php
$price = 8199000000;
$real = $price / 1e8;
echo $real, PHP_EOL; // 81.99

$price = 15499000000;
$real = $price / 1e8;
echo $real, PHP_EOL; // 154.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I should have just used a regex.....
^([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})0